# I get "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" when importing custom view

Tags: android-layout, import, nullpointerexception, custom-view, pinchzoom

I am trying to use custom view from "tutorial How to take advantage of the pinch-to-zoom feature in your Xperia™ X10 apps – Part 2" [here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tutorials/ui-graphics/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-pinch-to-zoom-feature-in-your-xperia-x10-apps-part-2/), I copied the classes related to the custom view to the project.  The custom view appears in xml editor->graphical layout->custom & library views, when I drag/drop it into the layout I get :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The logcat shows this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 01:00:19.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yav.android/iv.GeneralImageview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The question is how to make eclipse see this custom view class?